# Wire old 240 Vinduction motor for 120 V

Tags: induction-motor

I have a working motor taken from an old dryer. The motor plate says it runs on 120 V AC, but a separate housing on the motor for the connections indicates it runs on 240 V AC. When I opened the housing to investigate further, I am not quite sure how it works. Is there any way to get this to run on 120 V AC, and if there is, will it pull the 5.9 A the motor plate indicates?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### revised

Follow the numbers 1M to 6M on the schematic of your service manual like this one.

Note that Line is on 4M with Neutral on 5M then the momentary switch is bypassed by 6M ( via RUN SWITCH inside motor) from Neutral and switched off by Timer or Belt detect on line to 4M.

Keep in mind there is a separate start & stop to prevent heat aging on start switch from stopping arc.

[image]

### old guess

Most likely the motor uses a series heaters resistor from  240Vac 60Hz to boost starting current yet limited and then an inertial switch connects it to 120Vac 60Hz.  **This may be why it is MARKED only for a dryer.**  Typical induction motors use additional starter winding with Start Cap and Run cap for PF correction.

Why did you want to go to the trouble to convert this old motor?

Comment: I suspect that the 240V/25A text refers to the switch between 1-2 that turns on power to the dryer heating element ONLY when the motor is up to speed, the other contact is used to switch the starting winding. If the heating element was enabled without the motor going it would probably overheat and potentially cause a fire.

Comment: very good point .. until the fan belt breaks. while motor is spinning

Comment: then it will stop all together, there is another switch that disconnects power when the belt breaks.

Comment: When I connect line to 4M and neutral to 5M the motor does not start. I don't see how it's supposed to since both coils are pulling power through the capacitor. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see any cap

Comment: The third picture I posted, the cap sits between the blue wire and the two connected winding leads.

Answer (score 1):

a 240 motor it will run on 120V but available torque will be reduced

however your motor is a 120V  motor, it says that on the label,

The label on the switch housing describes the switching capability of the switch.